# Angular - Input as function that returns sequential values

Tags: angular

I have a component in Angular that has an input as a number because it renders differently depending on of it is even or odd in the list.

`<app-comp [number]=getNumberAndIncrement()></app-comp>`

`<app-comp [number]=getNumberAndIncrement()></app-comp>`

`<app-comp [number]=getNumberAndIncrement()></app-comp>`

where

```
count = 0;

getNumberAndIncrement() {
  return count++;
}
```

The issue is with the change detection. Obviously that function will return a different value every time it is called. But I just want to pass one value to the component and then forget about it, but it appears Angular would prefer the function for the input has no side effects. The benefit of the function is I can change the order of the components and not have to worry about retooling hard-coded numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private member and a setter to execute a function and run some checks so the private member "_number" will be instanced only one time (if it is not setted in this example) even if the input from the parent change

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    private _number: number;

    @Input() set number(parentNumber) {
      if (!this._number) {
        this._number = parentNumber;
      }
    }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need the index of your component which is rendered through a list?

If you nedd a unique index, then use the possibilities of `*ngFor` directive.

**Possibilities of `*ngFor`:**

- `index: number`: The index of the current item in the iterable.
- `first: boolean`: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
- `last: boolean`: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
- `even: boolean`: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
- `odd: boolean`: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

**1) How to define `index` in `*ngFor`:**

Here is an example for defining an index.

```
<app-comp *ngFor="let item of myArray; let myIndex = index; [number]="myIndex"></app-comp>
```

**2) How to get `even` and `odd` information in `*ngFor`:**

Declare own variables for `even` and `odd`.

```
<app-comp *ngFor="let item of myArray; let myIndex = index; let myEven = even; let myOdd = odd; [number]="myIndex"></app-comp>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ac7mho) is working example for above possibilities.

More description in official angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf):

Comment: This would work, but in order to do the `ngFor` I would have to, for example, load the components dynamically. I'd rather just declare the components one after the other.

Comment: You can use the way to create same elements
 ***ngFor="let i of [].constructor(3)"**